# llength not returning correct list size

Tags: tcl

I have a list which has the elements below.

```
test = {a[1] b[60] c[25] c[36]}
```

I am checking the length of test as below:

```
set result [llength ($test)]
```

This is giving me the error below:

```
list element in braces followed by ")" instead of space
```

What could be the issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [I cannot reproduce your error](http://codepad.org/0uBj1kQr)

Answer (score 1):

You might need to review the basics of [Tcl syntax](http://www.tcl-lang.org/about/language.html)

Don't put parenthesis around the argument to llength.

```
set x {test = {a[1] b[60] c[25] c[36]}}
set result [llength $x]
```

In future questions, it is better to post an entire program that can be 
executed so that your error can be reproduced easily.