# llength not returning the correct size for a list empty and non-empty elements

Tags: tcl

I am trying to get the length of the elements in the list.

My list has:

```
test = {} {a[1] b[2] c[3] d[4] e[5]}
```

When I do llength $test, I get 2, but I am expecting 5. How can fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry but how do you expect 5? I can see 2 elements in the list... Maybe you could [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) on your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62128382/1578604) to clarify?

Comment: You need to provide an example that is reproducable.

Comment: It would be easier to understand (And copy into tcl) if you use actual tcl commands and syntax for setting your `test` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Your list has two elements in it, and those elements are themselves lists with 0 and 5 sub-elements respectively. To get the length of those member lists, you use `llength` with `lindex`:

```
puts [llength [lindex $test 1]]
```